# Rectangle.contains() method never returns true

Tags: java, contains, rectangles

The diagram that i use returns a org.eclipse.draw2d.geometry.Rectangle with co-ordinates Rectangle(20.0, 450.0, 0.0, 0.0). I want to check if a point (20,450) is present within it.

I have tried this with contains and equals method. but it doesn't return true. what am i doing wrong?

```
if (rectangle.contains(new Point(20, 450)))
{
   return true;
}
```

I except the output to be true. I can change the co-ordinates of the point but not the co-ordinates of the rectangle.

Comment: I’m not familiar with that Rectangle class, but if it’s like java.awt.Rectangle, you appear to be creating a Rectangle with zero width and zero height, which means it cannot contain anything, even its own origin.

Comment: @VGR X, Y, width, height

Comment: Aren’t those last two parameters saying the rectangle has zero length and width? Isn’ It hard for it to contain something, then? (At least on its interior). I don’t have the rectangle api in front of me, so sorry if I am off track

Comment: @Michael Thank you for that (and for the link in your answer).  This does seem to confirm that the code is creating a rectangle with zero dimensions.

Comment: Where are you defining your variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdraw2d%2Fgeometry%2FRectangle.html) literally explains this.

> ```
> public boolean contains(double x, double y)
> ```
>
> Returns whether the given coordinates are within the boundaries of
>   this Rectangle. The boundaries are inclusive of the top and left
>   edges, but **exclusive of the bottom and right edges.**

Your point is the bottom right corner.